# Does a git hard reset remove stash?

Tags: git

Just wanted to understand if the `git reset --hard origin/master` command affect my stash stack. I am yet to try this out but I do not want it to reset my stash as I have some changes I want to apply after my branch is reset.

Comment: Without knowing the answer to this, the way I would find out is to create a new repository and TRY it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The hard reset command you showed above would move the HEAD pointer of whatever the current branch might be to `origin/master`, but it would not affect the stash commits, which are stored in `.git/refs/stash`.

Answer (score 19):

No, `git reset --hard origin/master` does not affect your stashes in any way.